# How do can you do fast random access to a CSR3 sparse matrix?

Tags: sparse-matrix, intel-mkl

I have a sparse matrix in CSR3 format used by MKL which is:

1D array `i()` indexed by row which gives the location of the start of each row.

1D array `j()` indexed by `i` which gives the column number of the *k*th non-zero element in the row. *column = j(i(row) + k)*.

1D array `a()` indexed by `i` which gives the value of the matrix element. *value = a(i(row) + k)*.

What's a fast way to find a matrix element at a given row and column?

What I do now is look up the start and end of the row in `i()`, then do a binary search through that interval of `j()` to find the required column. So that's *O(log(n))* where *n* is the number of non-zeros in a row. I hope for a *O(1)* method.

Comment: Could you please specify if you are using any Intel MKL routines?

Comment: Yes. MKL pardiso.